# What is the DTO pattern when you have multiple method calls but different request bodies?

Tags: java, spring, rest, dto

I was told that when building RestFul APIs, use nouns and not verbs. I was also told that each DTO gets its own controller. What does my DTO look like in the case that "edit property" and "add property" methods require two different request bodies?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/property")
public class PropertyController{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    //get properties method definition goes here

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    // edit property method definition goes here

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    // add property method definition goes here
}
```

edit property requires:

```
{
    "userloginid": "3333",
    "propertyname": "My edited property name",
    "propertyid": "1"
}
```

add property requires:

```
{
    "userloginid": "3333",
    "propertyname": "My new property name"
}
```

Comment: You can create two DTOs for each method, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/users/{loginid}/properties/{propertyid}` - please consider this endpoint as it is more RESTful

For PUT updates you can consider the endpoint above, and get your `userloginid` and `propertyid` from the Path Variables.

In the PUT request `PUT /users/3333/properties/1` I would send the following Request Body:

```
{
    "propertyname": "My edited property name"
}
```

For POST requests to create a new property I would consider sending a Request to this URL `/users/{loginid}/properties/` with the same Request Body structure:

```
{
    "propertyname": "My new property name"
}
```

As you can see I am not sending any ID in the POST request as ID generation for stored objects should happen in the DAO.

The client will receive the ID of the created/updated property in the Response Body:

```
{
    "propertyname": "My updated/created property name",
    "propertyid": "1"
}
```

So from the above examples, I would create two DTOs for handling the output and input situations.

Answer (score 0):

From your json data, your DTO might be

```
PropertyDTO{
    long userloginid;
    String propertyname;
    long propertyid;
}
```

So your API will look like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/property")
public class PropertyController{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public PropertyDTO get(){
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Boolean update(@RequestBody PropertyDTO dto){
        return true;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Boolean insert(@RequestBody PropertyDTO dto){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the same DTO with these three properties **(userloginid, propertyname, propertyid)**. But you have to consider that the **propertyid** can be **null**. Then when the request paramters are sent, if **propertyid** is not sent, the parser will create an instance of DTO with **propertyid=null**; else the parser will create an instance of DTO with **propertyid=value_passed_in parameter**.

Comment: so when I do a POST, it's completely okay for me to accept a DTO with a null field since I won't be using it?

Comment: @ShadyBears yes it is.